MudSelect String is truncated
I am trying to show a string inside a MudSelectItem, but the string is truncated when item is selected, altough it is displaying the entire string in the dropDown men.
I tried using the css class mud-select-input & setting the width of the Select box, but it did not work.
Dropdown menu is showing entire string - which is fine
Once selected, string is truncated
My knowledge of css is limited.
<MudDialog DisableSidePadding="true">
    <DialogContent>
         <MudContainer> 
            <MudSelect T="string" label="String to show" Placeholder="Please Select" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Class="pb-4 select"
                AnchorOrigin="Origin.BottomLeft" TransformOrigin="Origin.TopLeft" Adornment="Adornment.End">
                <MudSelectItem T="string" Value="@("This Is A Long String To Show")"/>
                <MudSelectItem T="string" Value="@("This Is Another Long String To Show")"/>
            </MudSelect>
        </MudContainer>
    </DialogContent>
    <DialogActions>
    </DialogActions>
</MudDialog>

<style>
.mud-select-input
{
    width:400px
    max-width:500px
}
</style>

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wuQoOIwyfcDfeTyS

I can't reproduce the issue described if your custom style is removed.

Can you remove 'select' from Class and see if that fixes the issue for you?

@Uerschel, remove select does not affecct anything.

@Anu6is, What do I set in my Theme to remove this effect ? Or can I override my Theme in this dialog box ?

I was referring to your <style> tags that attempt to limit the width. Note where the triangle icon is located. That's due to your custom style.

@Anu6is: With or without the 
I don't know what's different between your implementation and what you provided in the Try.MudBlazor link, but removing the custom style fixed the issue there. Outside of that I can't say what's wrong.
https://iili.io/JUAwfXn.png vs https://iili.io/JUAwSpI.png
